# rails form post to index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with

```
<% form_tag :controller => 'mycontroller', :action => 'index', :method => 'post'
```

But when i submit it... it goes to the mycontroller#create action.

why?  am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html and check this topic: 2 Resource Routing: the Rails Default

You are using the method post that defaults to the action create.

Comment: even with :method => 'get'  it still goes to create... :-/

Comment: It won't pass params to the index action.